# Is skydiving not NOTAMed in the US?

Tags: usa, skydiving, notam

Recently there was a mishap at South Lakeland Airport in Mulberry, Florida where a [Cessna 170 collided with a skydiver](http://www.flyingmag.com/technique/accidents/cessna-170b-pilot-and-skydiver-survive-collision). Luckily all involved suffered only minor injuries. As far as I know, skydiving in Germany must be NOTAMed, is this not the case in the US?

The incident was caught on a [series of stills](http://www.flyingmag.com/photo-gallery/photos/skydiver-and-cessna-170b-mid-air-collision-photos?pnid=47561):

[image: Skydiver vs. airplane]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[14 CFR 105](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr105_main_02.tpl) covers parachute operations in the USA.

There is not a requirement for a NOTAM, but since this happened at an uncontrolled airport the nearest ATC facility must be notified at least 1 hour in advance but not more than 24 hours in advance and, they must have approval from airport management.

Then for the actual jump, ATC must be notified at least 5 minutes prior to jump via radio from the aircraft.

---

> [**§105.23   Parachute operations over or onto airports.**](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=9378f3a8d784e1828fcf0b8edba51ffd&node=14:2.0.1.3.17.1.9.6&rgn=div8)
>
> No person may conduct a parachute operation, and no pilot in command
>   of an aircraft may allow a parachute operation to be conducted from
>   that aircraft, over or onto any airport unless—
>
> (a) For airports with an operating control tower:
>
> (1) Prior approval has been obtained from the management of the
>   airport to conduct parachute operations over or on that airport.
>
> (2) Approval has been obtained from the control tower to conduct
>   parachute operations over or onto that airport.
>
> (3) Two-way radio communications are maintained between the pilot of
>   the aircraft involved in the parachute operation and the control tower
>   of the airport over or onto which the parachute operation is being
>   conducted.
>
> (b) For airports without an operating control tower, prior approval
>   has been obtained from the management of the airport to conduct
>   parachute operations over or on that airport.
>
> (c) A parachutist may drift over that airport with a fully deployed
>   and properly functioning parachute if the parachutist is at least
>   2,000 feet above that airport's traffic pattern, and avoids creating a
>   hazard to air traffic or to persons and property on the ground.
>
> [**§105.25   Parachute operations in designated airspace.**](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=9378f3a8d784e1828fcf0b8edba51ffd&node=14:2.0.1.3.17.1.9.7&rgn=div8)
>
> (a) No person may conduct a parachute operation, and no pilot in
>   command of an aircraft may allow a parachute operation to be conducted
>   from that aircraft—
>
> (1) Over or within a restricted area or prohibited area unless the
>   controlling agency of the area concerned has authorized that parachute
>   operation;
>
> (2) Within or into a Class A, B, C, D airspace area without, or in
>   violation of the requirements of, an air traffic control authorization
>   issued under this section;
>
> (3) Except as provided in paragraph (c) and (d) of this section,
>   within or into Class E or G airspace area unless the air traffic
>   control facility having jurisdiction over the airspace at the first
>   intended exit altitude is notified of the parachute operation no
>   earlier than 24 hours before or no later than 1 hour before the
>   parachute operation begins.
>
> (b) Each request for a parachute operation authorization or
>   notification required under this section must be submitted to the air
>   traffic control facility having jurisdiction over the airspace at the
>   first intended exit altitude and must include the information
>   prescribed by §105.15(a) of this part.
>
> (c) For the purposes of paragraph (a)(3) of this section, air traffic
>   control facilities may accept a written notification from an
>   organization that conducts parachute operations and lists the
>   scheduled series of parachute operations to be conducted over a stated
>   period of time not longer than 12 calendar months. The notification
>   must contain the information prescribed by §105.15(a) of this part,
>   identify the responsible persons associated with that parachute
>   operation, and be submitted at least 15 days, but not more than 30
>   days, before the parachute operation begins. The FAA may revoke the
>   acceptance of the notification for any failure of the organization
>   conducting the parachute operations to comply with its requirements.
>
> (d) Paragraph (a)(3) of this section does not apply to a parachute
>   operation conducted by a member of an Armed Force within a restricted
>   area that extends upward from the surface when that area is under the
>   control of an Armed Force.

Even more information is available in [AC 105-2E](http://www.uspa.org/Portals/0/Downloads/AC105-2E.pdf).